# Vue router not following children paths

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm having problems to  make my http://localhost:8080/myapps/config route load. If I use http://localhost:8080/myapps everything works ok and I get a list of my apps. But when I want to access an app config through http://localhost:8080/myapps/config it loads the content of /myapps again. However, the url in my browser shows the correct path /myapps/config.

I have been checking the routher for some hours but everything seems to be ok. Could anybody shed some light?

My router file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

const MyApps = () => import('../views/app/subviews/MyApps');
const AppKeyValue = () => import('../views/app/subviews/AppKeyValue');

import MainView from '../views/app/MainView'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: 
    [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: MainView,
            redirect: 'myapps',
            children: 
            [
                {
                    path: 'myapps',
                    component: MyApps,
                    meta: 
                    {
                        requiresAuth: true,
                        breadcrumb: 'My Apps'
                    },
                    children:
                    [
                        {
                            path: 'config',
                            component: AppKeyValue,
                            meta: 
                            {
                                requiresAuth: true,
                                breadcrumb: 'App configuration'
                            }
                        },
                    ]

                },
            ]
        },
    ]
})
```

Everything works ok if I don't use child routes:

```
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes:
    [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: MainView,
            redirect: 'myapps',
            children: 
            [
                {
                    path: 'myapps',
                    component: MyApps,
                    meta: 
                    {
                        requiresAuth: true,
                        title: 'message.ecommerce',
                        breadcrumb: 'My Apps'
                    },
                },
                {
                    path: 'myapps/config',
                    component: AppKeyValue,
                    meta: 
                    {
                        requiresAuth: true,
                        title: 'message.ecommerce',
                        breadcrumb: 'App configuration'
                    }
                }
           ]
     }
]}
```

Comment: Do you have a <router-view/> in myapps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't post your `*.vue` components, but I assume you're missing `<router-view>` in the second level component.

Example:

`MainView` is mapped to `/` and has 1 children route (`/myapps`). You're probably using `<router-view>` in your `MainView`.

`MyApps` is mapped to `myapps` as a children of the `/`-route and has 1 children route (`/config`).

Add a `<router-view` to your `MyApps.vue` to let it display its children (which is just `/config` in your case).

> Similarly, a rendered component can also contain its own, nested `<router-view>`.

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html#nested-routes

BTW: That's also why your second router config is working: The main route has two children (`/myapps` and `/myapps/config`), which both get displayed by the `MainView`'s `<router-view>`.

Here is a working example from the documentation:

https://jsfiddle.net/nazgul_mamasheva/zrcLe9z7/1/